# Macports port install error: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, macports

I have been trying to install keybase on my OSX external dev drive. It fails to install gnupg. I ran

`sudo port clean gnupg`
and
 `sudo port -v install gnupg`
and then to get the details

`cat /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/main.log`

Is this an issue with my drive's paths? My other ports seem to be fine, and I selfupdate regularly. Thanks in advance.

```
:info:configure config.status: executing po-directories commands
    :info:configure config.status: creating po/POTFILES
    :info:configure config.status: creating po/Makefile
    :info:configure 
    :info:configure                 Version info:   gnupg 1.4.20
    :info:configure                 Configured for: Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0)
    :info:configure 
    :debug:configure Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
    :debug:build build phase started at Thu Jun  9 13:11:22 EDT 2016
    :notice:build --->  Building gnupg
    :debug:build Executing org.macports.build (gnupg)
    :debug:build Environment: 
    CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES'
    CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS'
    CPATH='/opt/local/include'
    LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib'
    MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.11'
    :debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/work/gnupg-1.4.20" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all'
    :debug:build Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/work/gnupg-1.4.20" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
    :info:build make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/work/gnupg-1.4.20'
    :info:build /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
    :info:build make: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory
    :info:build make: *** [all] Error 1
    :info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/work/gnupg-1.4.20'
    :info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/work/gnupg-1.4.20" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
    :info:build Exit code: 2
    :error:build org.macports.build for port gnupg returned: command execution failed
    :debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 12774 2
    :debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
        while executing
    "system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
        ("eval" body line 1)
        invoked from within
    "eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
        invoked from within
    "command_exec build"
        (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
        invoked from within
    "portbuild::build_main org.macports.build"
        ("eval" body line 1)
        invoked from within
    "eval $procedure $targetname"
    :info:build Warning: targets not executed for gnupg: org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
    :notice:build Please see the log file for port gnupg for details:
        /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_mail_gnupg/gnupg/main.log
```

Comment: You might want to consider using Homebrew instead, which is receiving much more development work and often ships much newer versions (and probably has much more applications listed by now).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a poorly written portfile, makefile, or build script failed to quote a path, so the space in your boot volume name "Macintosh HD" is being mishandled.

You could work around this buggy build file by removing the space from your volume name.

Comment: I now recall seeing this issue in the past, and am surprised it hasn't been fixed. Macports support suggests correcting the path to my xcode, via xcode-select. As I am booting off of a dev drive (and not sure if I am using a separate XCode, Dev Tools from my HD), I hesitate to do this without more info: what is the best practice so as to not break functionality of all other ports, dependencies, et al.?

Comment: @gurlinthewurld If it's acceptable to use the Xcode that's on the drive you've booted from, you could use `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`. If the volume named "Macintosh HD" is not your boot drive, and you still want to use the Xcode that's installed on that "Macintosh HD" volume, then you should probably remove the space in the name of the volume or otherwise make sure it's mounted to a mount point that doesn't have a space in the name.